# hangouts - How to see the properties of my partner to a discusson?

Tags: contacts, google-hangouts

It must be a simple question.

I'm chatting a while with the man. I have his contact in hangouts program (I have not his contact in my phone contacts).

I have added this chat by email. Now I want to see the email.
The email is *the main identifier*, and it must be there.
The question become principled.

It is so complicated, I can't figure it out.
How can I find the email of contact in hangouts?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get your interlocutor mail adress in Hangouts, go in the conversation, then click on the 3 dots (top right corner), then Partcipants and Options (not sure about the translation) now click on the green circle at the bottom of your screen and your contact's mail adress chouls appears.

[image]]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not know why, but I have not e-mail bullet in that tab(((

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Sony xperia M. Android 4.3.

Comment: Is your Hangouts updated ? The current version is 7.0.

Comment: Yes, it is. I think, it is a specific bug. I have not g+ account, and contacts are not in circles. I have added them in earlier versions of hangout. Program had no place to remember the properties and now it only has that in internal data, program has no method to convert to visible data and show me. This is what I suppose.